# React Virtualized - Changing the height of a List Row post render

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm using a `List` inside and `AutoSizer` with a dynamic height using a function for `rowHeight`. The row in my use case needs to render with ellipsis and expand upon clicking on it.

I'm wondering how to go about dynamically setting the `rowHeight` once the row has already been rendered?

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://rawgit.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/master/playground/tree.html) is an example of doing something similar (and [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/playground/tree.js) is the source code). The key part is [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/32454e0c85ce5bfea8b86154d1fa569022f2cb15/playground/tree.js#L9-L10):

```
// When height changes externally, let List know to reset its cached size
List.recomputeRowHeights()
List.forceUpdate()
```

Comment: from docs: `recomputeRowHeights()` - ... This method will also force a render cycle (via forceUpdate) ...